# move container to center and ajust text for show view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i have view show that is display item of car
I want to organize dispalyed text when i use `class="text-center"` is move the item to center but is not organized like i want . see my attached file

and this is code

```html
<div class="container" style= "word-break: break-all">
        <div class="text-left">                
         <div >
                    <h3>L'id de la voiture est :
                        {{Car.id}}
                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                        Model :
                        {{Car.getModel}}
                    </h3>
                    <h3>nom :
                        {{Car.name}}</h3>
                    <h3>Prix :{{Car.price}}
                    </h3>
                    
                    {% if Car.image.name is defined %}
                        <p>
                            <h3>price :
                                <img width="100px" height="100px" src="{{ asset('pic/')~Car.image.name  }}">
                            </h3>
                        </p>
                    {% else %}
                        <p>
                            <h3>price :</h3>
                            aucune image isérée</p>
                    {% endif %}
                    
                    {% for keyword in Car.keywords %}
                    
                        <p>
                            {{ keyword.name }}
                            {% if not loop.last %},
                            {% endif %}
                        </p>
                    
                    {% endfor %}
                    
                    {% if Car.cities | length > 0 %}
                        <p>
                            {% for city in Car.cities %}
                                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
                                    <i class="material-icons left">
                                        {{ city.name }}</i>
                                </a>
                                {% if not loop.last %}{% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <a href="{{path('library')}}">Accueil</a>
         </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is what i want but is located on left
[image]

I want it like that but position on center without change text
[image]

Comment: have you tried  align='center' in the div?

Comment: yes is move  on center but text is not organazed that is the issue see my attached picture thanksthanks

Comment: Just add style="width:100px; margin:0 auto;" in the second div, and the it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want is some offset on the left

```css
.offset-center {
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  min-width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="word-break: break-all">
  <div class="text-left offset-center">
    <div>
      <h3>L'id de la voiture est : {{Car.id}}</h3>
      <h3>Model : {{Car.getModel}}</h3>
      <h3>nom : {{Car.name}}</h3>
      <h3>Prix :{{Car.price}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes true but is donsn't work for me because i include this view on other master page thats why i think

Comment: is work thanks but i  want someway how move text to center  without do offset you understand me daut thank dear

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want is centered div and text.

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
  align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="word-break: break-all">
  <div class="text-left centered">
    <div>
      <h3>L'id de la voiture est : {{Car.id}}</h3>
      <h3>Model : {{Car.getModel}}</h3>
      <h3>nom : {{Car.name}}</h3>
      <h3>Prix :{{Car.price}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```